# Pass-by-reference template functions with `const char *` specialisation

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have a template function:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T const & t);
```

And some specialisations of that function:

```
template<> void foo<int>(int const & t) {
  cout << t << endl;
}

template<> void foo<const char *>(const char * const & t) {
  cout << t << endl;
}
```

And some ways I want to call that function:

```
foo(3);
foo("Hello, world.");
```

But I can't figure out how to formulate the template so that template type deduction gets literals of both `int` and `const char *` right.  If I do the above, then I get `undefined reference to void foo<char [14]>(char const [14] &)`.  I tried recasting the template like this:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T t);

template<> void foo<int>(int t) { ... }
template<> void foo<const char *>(const char * t) { ... }
```

which works, but of course now I get call-by-value semantics, requiring any class types that I use as the template parameter to have a copy constructor.

Is there no way to write a pass-by-reference template function with a `const char *` specialisation that works?

Comment: [FYI] String literals have the type `const char[n]` not `const char *`.

Comment: Any reason to prefer `template<> void foo<int>(int const & t)` over `template<> void foo<int>(int t)`? I prefer to pass by value primitive type instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
foo("Hello, world.");
```

Doesn't call `foo<const char*>`. It calls `foo<char[14]>`, since `foo` takes a `T const&`. Your specialization isn't called since it isn't the same type as the template.

That said, just don't specialize. Overload:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T const& );

void foo(int const& );

void foo(char const* );
```

It's way easier to reason about and is more likely to do what you actually want.

Comment: Of course.  Adding overloading into the mix is what I was missing.  Thanks.

Comment: I understood the first bit - just not how to get the effect I was looking for.